# How to off jquery function?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know how to off jquery event like this:

```
$("#element").off();
```

but I've function and I need to off my function when window resize.how can I off my `changeBg()` function ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function changeBg(element) {
    $(element).on("click", function() {
      $(this).css("background", "lightblue");
    })
  }

  changeBg("p");


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>click to change my background</p>
<p>me to!</p>


<button>Make passive</button>
```

Comment: `$(element).off();` if you want to wrap that in a function called `changeBgOff` then that's up to you.

Comment: I need to off only function not element

Comment: do it unbind when screen change .... Do it unbind or preventdefault

Comment: You might delete the element and insert an identical one but with a different id.

Comment: So add a boolean check inside the function to a global variable. What you are asking doesn't make much sense but that is what I think you are getting at.

Comment: Exactly as above, just use a global variable... you don't need to over complicate it.

Comment: so is there any idea to understand ? because I'm new on jquery and I'm keen on learn :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a named function and unbind it with `resize()`.

```js
function changeBG( e ) {
  $( this ).css( 'background-color', 'lightblue' );
}

var $p = $( 'p' );

$p.on( 'click', changeBG );

$( window ).resize( function ( e ) {
  $p.off( 'click', changeBG );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Change Me!</p>

<p>Me too!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `off` your function when window is resized.

This snippet is not working here because snippet window is not resizable, try it here [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/8rhocL89/)

```js
function changeBg(element, type) {
 if(type == true) {
  $(element).on("click", function() {
   $(this).css("background", "lightblue");
  })
 }
 else {
  $(element).off("click");
 }
}
 
$(document).ready(function() {
 changeBg("p", true);
});


$(window).resize(function() {
 changeBg("p", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>click to change my background</p>
<p>me to!</p>
<button>Make passive</button>
```